# how do add/push given fields in mongodb?What will be the mondodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So this is my collection snippet:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d82c76c07d41a38d418120"),
        "userid" : "a",
        "dates" : {
                "2/01/2015" : {
                        "9/10" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        },
                        "10/11" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        }
                },
                "3/01/2015" : {
                        "9/10" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        },
                        "10/11" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        }
                }}}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d82c76c07d41a38d418120"),
        "userid" : "b",
        "dates" : {
                "2/01/2015" : {
                        "9/10" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        },
                        "10/11" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        }
                },
                "3/01/2015" : {
                        "9/10" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        },
                        "10/11" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        }
                }}}
```

I want to add/push given given snippet into user id:b ,dates fiels:
Snippet:

```
"4/01/2015" : {
                        "9/10" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        },
                        "10/11" : {
                                "ava" : "yes",
                                "bookibg_id" : "null"
                        }
                }
```

So I want to add the snippet dates>snippet where userid=b
What will be the mongodb query?
I searched about $push on mongo docs but it says that the field needs to be an array otherwise it wont happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
db.dates.update({"userid":"b"}, {$set:{"dates.4/01/2015":{
                    "9/10" : {
                            "ava" : "yes",
                            "bookibg_id" : "null"
                    },
                    "10/11" : {
                            "ava" : "yes",
                            "bookibg_id" : "null"
                    }
            } }})
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this kind of things

for this you have to find the document then add new value in the object then update the object